# mysql union with fulltext search error

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, union

I write a query to get results using my sql full text search with union. but it getting a error i tried a lot and can't correct. the error is

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE MATCH(product_name) AGAINST ('+epson +kit' IN BOOLEAN
>   MODE) AND p.publ' at line 3

```
  SELECT 
p.virtuemart_product_id, l.product_name 
FROM jos_virtuemart_products AS p, jos_virtuemart_products_dk WHERE
MATCH(1.product_name) AGAINST ('+epson +kit' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AND p.published = '1' 
AND p.virtuemart_product_id = l.virtuemart_product_id LIMIT 0,25
UNION(SELECT 
p.virtuemart_product_id, l.product_name 
FROM jos_virtuemart_products AS p, jos_virtuemart_products_dk WHERE 
MATCH(product_sku) AGAINST ('+epson +kit' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AND p.published = '1'
AND p.virtuemart_product_id = l.virtuemart_product_id LIMIT 0,25
)
```

Can anyone help me to correct this.
Thank You

Comment: You should a a table name between `FROM` and `WHERE`...

Comment: sorry i couldn't copy that before correctly, i change that as above still getting same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in ... MATCH(1.product_name) ...
You are using the number 1 instead of the character l (L) 
they look similar though :)